# textboxes wont stay on the same line

Tags: css, asp.net

I have a bunch of textboxes long with labels and RequiredFieldValidators. My problem is that they refuse to place themselves on the same line. Always label->newline->textbox->newline->label->etc.

I dont really know what makes them end up on new lines, but here's a short stub from my code. I have looked in the classes and with chromes "inspect element" tool but can't figure out why they are all on new lines. Can someone help?

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnl1" runat="server" Width="1700">        
    <fieldset class="inputForm fullscreen" style="width:auto;"> //I've tried adding display:inline here
        <legend>
            Definition
        </legend>
        <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="Name" /><asp:TextBox ID="tbName" runat="server" /><asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="req_Name" ControlToValidate="tbName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" CssClass="ErrorText" />
        <asp:Label ID="lblSource" runat="server" text="source" /><asp:TextBox ID="tbSource" runat="server" /><asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="req_Source" ControlToValidate="tbSource" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" CssClass="ErrorText" /><br />
    </fieldset>
</asp: Panel>
```

Comment: Can u post html code here and if possible fiddle for it.

Comment: Please replicate in an http://jsfiddle.net so we can see exactly what you mean.  Also does this happen in particular browsers?

Comment: I'l try to replicate it. It's the same in other browsers.

Comment: can you provide the class fieldSetClass?

Comment: Try a css rule like    label, input{float:left;} , Copy this style to your own style sheet

Comment: @AjuMon sorry, that wasn't supposed to be there, I fixed it now :P I made this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zZD9b/ but the problem doesn't occur :S

Comment: I tried putting everything in a div and setting `float:right` which worked. But I dont want everything on the right either..

Comment: Both `span` and `input` are inline elements. If you remove the CSS classes from the `fieldset` do you get all the controls on the same line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it was the "fullscreen" class that messed it up. I removed that class and it worked fine. Thanks all for your help!

Comment: Please mark this as your accepted solution when you can. That way others can find this as an answered question.

Comment: @pixelmeow yes, I know. I'll mark it as correct in 2 days ^^

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

- As @Jaison said, try using the float:left in your css on both the labels and textboxes,
- Set the width of the labels to something like width:70px in your css,
- Place controls within the "span" element,
- Place a break, "br", before the validator as they sometimes tend to take up space even when not visible.

Comment: Instead of using a server side label control, try using raw text: e.g Name: &nbsp; <asp:textbox...